# My Windows Phone 8 is not detected in WMWare

Tags: windows-phone-8, vmware, detect, xap

I've installed Windows 8 OS in VMWare, Visual Studio 2012 and Windows Phone SDKs in my workPC. I've similar environment in an other PC, my homePC. I was able to unlock my Windows Phone 8 and install one application into my phone using homePC.

Now both PCs don't detect my Windows Phone and I can't install any applications for testing purposes in my WinPhone. Both pcs give same error message: "Connection to device failed. No windows phone was detected."

I've seached the internet to find the solution but no luck. Can anyone help me? What to do? Where to start to find the cause for this.

Answer (score 0):

open task manager, go to the tab "services" and restart or start (if it is stopped) "IpOverUsbSvc" service...

Comment: No go here. Having same issue as OP.

Comment: It took 9 months, lol. However, I'm happy that your problem is solved.